# Динамические библиотеки c++ Mac OS

Tags: c++, macos, библиотеки

Я новичок в C++.
Работаю на Macbook.
Долго искала в интернете про создание и подключение библиотек
Возник вопрос.
Есть ли возможные способы подключить dylib к проекту без заголовочного файла ?
Например, на Windows  в VS есть такая возможность.

Comment: Да, ровно так же как на Линукс, т.е. dlopen, dlsym, и т.д.

Comment: спасибо Вам огромное, без вашей подсказки бы не справилась!